# mosquitto broker service ubuntu16.04

Tags: ubuntu, server, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

i am trying to setup a mosquitto broker on my ubuntu16.04 server.
I can start, stop , restart ... etc. the broker with:

```
/etc/init.d/mosquitto start/stop
```

But how can i restart the service with my own config file?

I have to start the broker with:

```
mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

1495978951: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Fri, 19 Feb 2016 12:03:16 +0100) starting
1495978951: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1495978951: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1495978951: Error: Address already in use
```

But before i can start the broker like this i have to kill the mosquitto service. How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your using the same config file as the service `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` so they are both going to be configured to use the same network port.

Unless you use a different configuration file with a different port (using either `port` or `listen` directives) then one is always going to fail to start if the other is running.

The choices are:

1. Stop the service with `service mosquitto stop` and run your own instance manually
2. Edit the default config file to match what you want and restart the service (`service mosquitto restart`)
3. Use a separate config file for the manual version and configure it with a different port number.